# Google Drive sdk Standard error code Documentation

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

We are using google drive APIs in our android application. We want to show particular error scenarios of the google drive api in our own custom messages.

For example: When the user exceeds the storage rate limit the SDK throws an exception where the exception content has the JSON HTTP response error like below.

> 

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
        "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
  }
}
```

I have a generic exception handler which handles all exceptions with 403 error code. But we want to handle the "dailyLimitExceeded" scenario which we can identify by inspecting the "reason" field in error response. We are referring [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors) documentation but we cannot find any exhaustive list of all error scenarios along with error code/reason.

**Is there any documentation available which lists all error code/reason of google drive API ?**